# 2X2 Factorial Design with Likert-type Responses

Tags: regression, categorical-data, likert, ordered-logit

I have a 2x2 design completely between subjects. Both independent variables are dichotomous. The dependent variable is a 7 point Likert-type item. But I'm not sure how to analyze it. I know ANOVA, while common, is wrong because the Likert data is ordinal. And I want to look at interaction effects, so a one-way test isn't helpful. Is ordinal logistic regression the way to go? If so, how should I implement it in R?

Comment: I have used UCLA's IDRE procedures before. They have one for ordinal logistic regression: https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/ordinal-logistic-regression/